# How to subset a very large HDF5 dataset from file and write to another file?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, hdf5, h5py

I have a very large dense matrix (1M * 30K) stored in a hdf5 file. I was able to read the hdf5 file using `h5py` using the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

f = h5py.File('myFile.hdf5', 'r')
mat = f['matrix']
# sub_mat = mat[:, :1000]
# write sub_mat into another hdf5 file
```

I want to subset the matrix to get a `sub_mat` consisting only the first 1000 columns and write the `sub_mat` into another hdf5 file. Note the `sub_mat` has a shape of (1M * 1K), which is also too large to be loaded into RAM. How could I do that?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I find your question a bit confusing ... if the 1,000,000x1000 submatrix is too large to load in memory, surely your bottleneck would be that the 1,000,000x30,000 matrix is way too big to load into memory via `mat = f['matrix']` in the first place, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now, `mat` is probably just a reference to the object corresponding to `f['matrix']` ... which I'm assuming has some underlying functionality to get the data straight from the file rather than loading them in memory (or something along those lines), right? In which case you don't want to slice it as that would actually create a new object in memory.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, correct. `mat` is a reference of the large matrix in the hdf5 file. It is not evaluated until I explicitly call `mat[:, :1000]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the docs of `h5py`, I found there's a classmethod for [`h5py.Dataset`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html) named `write_direct` that can directly write matrix to file.

Therefore what I need to do is to create another h5 file first, then create a dataset, and call this method to write the large matrix to file directly:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

f = h5py.File('myFile.hdf5', 'r')
mat = f['matrix']

f2 = h5py.File('mySubmat.hdf5', 'w')
dset = f2.create_dataset('sub_matrix', shape=(mat.shape[0], 1000), dtype=np.float32)
dset.write_direct(mat[:, :1000])
f2.close()
```